# socket.io including in project and installation

Tags: node.js, socket.io, npm

Im want to include socket.io in my project. I installed it using `npm install -g socket.io` still being in directory my files to the project are located in.
I created script to test if it was successfull

i creater server.js with code

```
var client=require("socket.io").listen(8080).sockets;

client.on("connection",function(socket){

    console.log("Someone has connected")

})
```

and included in html file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

I tried to run node server.js to see if there will be message in console but there wasnt , . Whad did i do wrong? I a trying to solve this  problem but can find solution. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must initialize a connection in html file (on client side).

If you are trying to connect to the host that serves the page you can use:

```
var socket = io();
```

or specify address:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8080');
```